# How to automate the Flatten function in Change Event in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I can use the flatten function to view in column A: The contents of B column then below it the contents of C column.

[image]

But I have two problems:

1. How to apply that for the used range in B and C columns?
2. How to automate that result. so it happens on every change event happen in this sheet(Tab)

I tried `=FLATTEN(B1:B,C1:C)` but it is equal #ref. And I have tried to record a macro. but I can't define a suitable range (Because I need that to apply to the used range in B&C columns). And I don't know how to make this function calculate with every change event in the sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can you test this out:*

```js
=tocol(B:C,1,1)
```

Comment: Thanks! this is gonna work! would u kindly tell me if there is a way to get data from two separate columns with tocol (or any other)? for example E & Z ?

Comment: use `hstack(E:E,Z:Z)` in place of `B:C` (above formula)

Comment: Brilliaaaaaaant :) Thanks!